# table разъезжается

Tags: html, css, width

Есть огромная таблица на 3-5 тыс строк. После загрузки в некоторых браузерах она разъезжается более ширины экрана. Стоит width=1000, max-width:100 и ничего не помогает. В Safari отображается отлично, в chrome разъезжается примерно до 3000 пикселей в ширину. Возможно реализовать строгую ширину?

Comment: width: 99% пробовали?

Comment: попробовал, не помогло